# SSIS Single Server ETL to Warehouse

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I am transforming sets from our transactional database to warehouse. There is only one source server and no other data sources (such as web services, flat files, Excel, etc.).

The jobs would be simple enough to write in TSQL Stored Procs. 
I wanted to still model the work in SSIS for the benefit of clarity, documentation, scalability, etc.

The SSIS modeling seems to be exponentially longer to implement. The question would be: does the benefit of SSIS ETL modeling provide the ROI compared to straight SPs?

Comment: There is a benefit only if your support team can only use visual tools and not SQL. I admit SP's can get long and complicated and it can be difficult to view mappings etc. but there are still many things in SSIS (Update task, SCD component, lookups) which are completely inferior to their T-SQL counterpart. I am busy convincing my team to use it as an orchestration tool that mostly imports data and runs stored procedures

Comment: I still need to process ssas partitions/dimensions and it just felt a little dirty leaving a proc execution alone there going to a ssas processing task.  One thing that gets frustrating though is having to micromanage some simple tasks like sorting for a left join or type conversion that would be implicit in TSQL.

Comment: In my list of crappy things in SSIS  I forgot to mention.... why would you ever do a join inside the SSIS tool and not in the database? Maybe helpful if you are joining disparate systems but you will find in time that you will give up and do it all in a staging table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SSIS modeling seems to be exponentially longer to implement.

Currently, that may be the case, but do you have any indication that you're going to gain any fluency? Start out with doing the complicated things with an SP as the datasource inside SSIS. This may help you to get the project started on time.

Later, as you grow more comfortable with SSIS and/or additional resources with a skill set for SSIS (DBA?) can be added to the team. There are a lot of debugging and administration tools in SSIS to monitor small pieces of long and complex data flows. You may find this to be very valuable in fixing a difficult problem instead a large proc.

For your first project using a technology, start small. The worse thing that could happen is your logic sits in the SP(s) forever. Hopefully, you trim down the time to implement even complex data translations.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I try to compose literate procs to ease maintenance, I thought with SSIS intent would be even more transparent. I also thought that SSIS makes me think things through more thoroughly then following a single train of thought. Seems also to leave room to scale as well as modularity. Always harder to sell quality (as sad as it may be in as far as the industry has grown).